# Providing Links for Validation

Tags: discussion

What it be appropriate to ask another member to provide a link to reference his answer here:

- [Is there a rule to know when to pronounce letter c as a "soft c" (s) or "hard c" (k)?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/18299/how-do-i-spell-the-letter-c)

Perhaps in a bottom-section. For this type of question, that would allow me to more simply check/validate his answser so I can give him points.  I have faith JMB is prob right, but in general I cannot know if someone is just making some things up off the top of their head.

Comment: Most of the time I don't think answerers are going to *have* references; sometimes, maybe, but I know that I at least tend to answer questions I already know the answer to, and also if there was a very easy-to-find and clear reference, there's at least a decent chance the OP would have found it, rather than asking here. A good rule of thumb when you're not sure if an answer is correct is to check the up votes.

Comment: People who *do* think an answer is right or wrong will vote. If you want to try to google to verify the answer before voting, that's perfectly fair. But I don't think we should start asking for sources on every answer. The idea behind SE is that we solicit expert answers, after all; AFAIK, the idea is that the experts *are* the source/

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this WendiKidd!  It's better if I take the burden on me (mostly) - I can google and check if I'm concerned.  But you've raised another philosophical question I'll need to consider.  The idea is that we are experts, yet we are not the experts on all things.  We need to research some answers (at least I do), and I'll give references for my research. To me, that's the Right Thing to Do.  So yeah, all of the sudden I see a bit of conflict between SE "frowning" on links and standard scientific protocol requiring proper referencing.

Comment: I don't know that I'd say SE frowns on links. Links can be great additions to answers, and if you took any significant portion of your answer from a source, you should cite it. Answers should contain all info necessary to answer the question; you shouldn't have to visit a link to get an answer. But supplementary links are absolutely a good thing. I just don't think requesting the answerer add a source as "proof" that they're correct is productive. If that makes any sense? :)

Comment: On a related note, I saw [a recent comment of yours asking for a reference](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/18310/i-found-a-mistake-on-yahoo#comment33583_18311).  I think it'd be better if you simply wrote "Could you provide a reference to back up your comment?" and left out the meta discussion about "community building" and so forth.  It's difficult for learners to read large volumes of text, so we do a service to them when we stay on task on the main site.  If you want to ask for a reference, you can ask for a reference; if you want to talk about community building, head to meta :-)

Comment: @CoolHandLouis Linking to references to support your answers is fine.  But if all you want to do is give references and not write an answer, you can leave those in a comment.  Answers are for answers.

Comment: Well, there are a lot of Native speakers of English answering questions on Ell stack, I trust that an answer coming from them will be a valid answer most of the times even if it is from the top of their head. You cannot expect people to hunt for reference links when the answer they provided is solid and cannot be disproved (that seems to be the case in the example you have provided), expecting reference links for every answer just makes the task of answering questions on the fly more laborious, I would say it will be good exercise for the O.P to conduct further verification if necessary.